# which one faster concurrent_queue<> vs mutex-ed queue<> during iteration

Tags: c++, algorithm, iterator, performance, containers

suppose you want to iterate all item in the queue which implemented using `concurrent_queue<>` and `std:queue<>`.

Since on `concurrent_queue<>` there is no iterator, so I can only think that I need to do `try_pop()` and `push()` until you pop-ed and re-push-ed all items in the `concurrent_queue<>`.

which one is more efficient in multithreaded condition?, doing that, or just use iterator of `queue<>` and lock it using critical section or other mutex.

I know just do test and benchmark it will answer my question, but I need to know the reason why one is should be faster than other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in a multithreaded environment and you push/pop from the queue to check it, won't other threads see imprecise data if you context-switch between a pop and a push operation? And another thread might push another object off, so the first thread would miss it... etc.

It's just too complicated, too fraught with race conditions. You'd have to lock on the queue as you do the iteration to guarantee data accuracy.

At that point, the question becomes: Is it faster to lock on the queue and use an iterator, or lock on the queue and repeatedly pop/push? I think you can guess which is the better option here :-)